# Given the real numbers $x_1,y_1,z_1,x_2,y_2,z_2,x_3,y_3$ and $z_3$, prove this determinant equality:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

$$(x_1+y_1+z_1)\begin{vmatrix}x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \newline x_2 & y_2 &z_2 \newline x_3 & y_3 & z_3\end{vmatrix} =  \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 &1 \newline \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & z_1 \newline y_2 & z_2
\end{vmatrix} & -\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & z_1 \newline x_2 & z_2
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \newline x_2 & y_2
\end{vmatrix} \newline \begin{vmatrix}
y_1 & z_1 \newline y_3 & z_3
\end{vmatrix} & -\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & z_1 \newline x_3 & z_3
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \newline x_3 & y_3
\end{vmatrix} \end{vmatrix}$$

I found this equality playing with barycentric coordinates. It took me very long to figure that it is the case and I wonder if someone can come up with a simple proof for it.

I did expand it all with wolframalpha and concluded it was true, I just can't figure the logic behind it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_i$ denote the row vector $v_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $i=1,2,3$. Let $e$ denote the vector $e = (1,1,1)$. We can write your equation as

$$
(v_1 \cdot e) \det\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3} = \det\pmatrix{e\\v_1\times v_2\\ v_1 \times v_3}
$$
where $\cdot$ denotes a dot-product and $\times$ a cross-product.

The right hand side can be written as the "scalar triple product"
$$
\det\pmatrix{e\\v_1\times v_2\\ v_1 \times v_3} = [(v_1 \times v_2) \times (v_1 \times v_3)] \cdot e.
$$
From here, we can make use of the [following identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Triple_product_expansion):
$$
(a \times b)\times(a \times c) = (a \cdot (b \times c)) a.
$$
Thus, we can write
$$
[(v_1 \times v_2) \times (v_1 \times v_3)] \cdot e =
[(v_1 \cdot (v_2 \times v_3))v_1]\cdot e 
\\ = [v_1 \cdot (v_2 \times v_3)](v_1\cdot e) 
\\ = \det\pmatrix{v_1\\v_2\\v_3} (v_1 \cdot e),
$$
which matches the left hand side of the equation.